# Combining a string and user input in C

Tags: c

I'm brand new to C, and I was wondering how to combine a string with a user's input. This is what I had, I'm not sure if the user input is correct though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int a;
    int input = scanf("%d", &a);
    printf ("Hello, \n" + input);
}
```

But this just asks for input, then prints to the terminal "Hello, ". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: printf ("Hello %d\n", input);

Comment: I think you need to read a textbook or tutorial to learn the basics. The chapter on `printf` should have the answer to your question.

Comment: Read a basic C book or tutorial. Not trying to be rude but it'll be more productive for you and for the SO community if you do basic research on your own before asking a question.

Comment: @user3121023: yes i wrote an answer specifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&d` read digits not characters. You must read characters with `%s`, because you want got combine a string, like you say, and scanf don't need return integer.

```
char str[200];
scanf("%s", str);
printf("Hello, %s", str);
```

Comment: `&d` : typo. `&str`: type mismatch. `"%s"` : There is a possibility to cause a buffer overrun.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY He say he combine a string with a user's input. This is reason for `%s`

Comment: I undarstand it. See [this](http://ideone.com/2s00tU)

Comment: Yea. You have right. I don't need references of char array. Now it's work without warning. @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `scanf` function does not return the matched value, but the number of values matched. The input value itself is written to the memory location pointed to by the second parameter, in your case, the variable `a`. See the [manual page for `scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) (or `man 3p scanf`) for details.

Second, a more correct `printf` statement would be something like this:

```
printf ("Hello, %d\n", a);
```

where `%d` in the format string is replaced with the integer `a`, e.g. if `a` equals 42, then the statement would have the same effect as `printf("Hello, 42\n");`. The `%d` specifier denotes that the respective argument is an integer. See the [manual page for `printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) (or `man 3p fprintf`) for details.

When you add a C-style string (e.g. `"Hello, \n"`) and an integers (e.g. `a`) directly using the `+` operator, there is no integer to string conversion taking place. Instead, the string literal as the first operand is considered as a `char const *` pointer to which the second operand, integer `a`, is added to. In which case the format string would point to some strange, which could lead to a crash or security vulnerability. For example, `printf("Hello, World!\n" + 7);` is equivalent to `printf("World!\n");` and only outputs the string "World!\n".

However, `"Hello, World!\n" + someLargeInteger` will point to some other data in your resulting binary or even outside the binary. This will cause undefined behaviour and might crash your program. Also note that values of type `int` might be negative.

Comment: I tried this, but it just printed "Hello, 0"

Comment: @Winj42 What did you want it to print?

Answer (score 1):

In C, scanf returns the count of successfull items matched.

The content of the input is in `a`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf ("Hello %d\n", a);
}
```